# Select ..... where .... OR 

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to select data where any one of multiple conditions occur on the same field?

Example: I would typically write a statement such as:

```
select * from TABLE where field = 1 or field = 2 or field = 3
```

Is there a way to instead say something like:

```
select * from TABLE where field = 1 || 2 || 3
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sure thing, the simplest way is this:

```
select foo from bar where baz in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
select * from TABLE where field IN (1,2,3)
```

You can also conveniently combine this with a subquery that only returns one field:

```
    select * from TABLE where field IN (SELECT boom FROM anotherTable)
```

Answer (score 5):

OR:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

Answer (score 3):

select * from TABLE where field in (1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE field IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use in for

```
select *
from table
where field  = '1' or field = '2' or field = '3'
```

its just

```
select * from table where field in ('1','2','3')
```

Answer (score 0):

while `in` is a shortcut for `or` and I wasn't sure how I could combine `in` with `and`, I did it this way

```
 SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE column1='x' AND (column2='y' OR column2='z');
```