# mysql where clause using 'IN" or multiple 'OR'

Tags: php, mysql

assuming query multiple conditions,

```
select AA.*,BB.* from AA left join BB on AA.key=BB.key 
where AA.key='red' or AA.key='green' or AA.key='blue' or AA.key='pink'
```

compare to

```
select AA.*,BB.* from AA left join BB on AA.key=BB.key 
where AA.key IN ['red','green',blue',pink']
```

In MYSQL, is any of the 2 options above faster than the other?
I know using 'IN" is more pretty, but is it different in speed?
(The tables have index on 'key')

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870/select-where-or) post, but there is not reference about speed.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Might be faster than asking here.

Comment: Actually, I'd bet on `BETWEEN 1 AND 100` being the fastest.

Comment: you can make both faster by defining indexes.

Comment: the number are not orderings, BETWEEN not work. is just to simplify the question.  could be also
.. IN ['this','that','red',green']

I just would like to know if  'IN"  is slower/faster than multiple 'OR'

Comment: a larger query (also with IN) is always faster than handle a result set with n unwanted results and check it with php **BUT if** ur WHERE includes almost all keys but one or two, then u will probably didnt notice any faster type of handling

Comment: I think the difference is not significant.

Comment: it is significant for me, because I have several hundred of those type of queries per second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RJS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4336989/rjs) IN clause is more faster then Multiple OR statement in SQL.

for example if you have 3 to 5 thousand record then IN query will be 5(approx) time faster as compared to the multiple OR statement.

Comment: That's what I was asking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The really best way to improve it is to have the desired keys in a another table with an index, and to join it:

```
Select AA.*, BB.*
From AA
Join KEYS using (key)
Left Join BB using (key)
```

MySQL will choose the best way regarding the size of KEYS and make it almost instant.

In general, avoid OR statement, they tend to be translated in union, which are not that great in performance.

Comment: And this is going to be faster *how*? Apart from your query syntax being invalid ...

Comment: The syntax is correct, I've just tested it on my server. The improve will be on big collection of keys, were MySQL will hash everything to go faster than simple string comparison. On a 100 elements collection, there is no big difference with the IN statement, that's true. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The `IN (...)` and `OR` forms will result in the same query plan, but the `IN()` form is easier to parse, so less time is spent in the parser and optimizer stages.